# Post message to a place using Google maps

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, google-maps

Is it possible to post a message to a place indicated by a user using Google Maps API ? I'm using ASP.NET/C#.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by 'message' and 'post to a place'? For all intents and purposes, this could mean 'print out a letter, put it in a paper envelope and mail it to the address that matches the selected geocoords'.

Comment: do you want to send email to all user's/clients (of your database) who belongs from the city/place selected by user in google map?

Comment: I didn't write any code for this. It was just an optional feature in a large application, but which I won't implement anymore. Or at least in the near future. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the Google Maps Data API.

From the documentation (Javascript version):

> Features are created by passing a FeatureEntry object to insertEntry() on the feature feed.

You can read the rest of the steps (too many to post on here) in [the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/mapsdata/developers_guide_javascript.html#creating_a_feature). This is assuming that you are using the javascript version of the API.